# AuthorizationFailed - "The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx does not have authorization to perform action

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I've tried to get Workspace from config which I do have access to, but it fails with the following error:

```
import azureml.core

print("SDK version:", azureml.core.VERSION)

from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
print(ws.name, ws.resource_group, ws.location, ws.subscription_id, sep='\n')
```

> SDK version: 0.1.80 Found the config file in:
>   C:\Users\gubert\Repos\Gimmonix\HotelMappingAI\aml_config\config.json
>   get_workspace error using subscription_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
>   resource_group_name=xxxxxxxxxxxx, workspace_name=gmx-ml-mapping
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml_project_commands.py",
>   line 320, in get_workspace workspace_name) File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml_base_sdk_common\workspace\operations\workspaces_operations.py",
>   line 78, in get raise
>   models.ErrorResponseWrapperException(self._deserialize, response)
>   azureml._base_sdk_common.workspace.models.error_response_wrapper.ErrorResponseWrapperException:
>   Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py",
>   line 38, in  main(sys.argv) File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_main_.py",
>   line 265, in main wait=args.wait) File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_main_.py",
>   line 256, in handle_args run_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_local.py",
>   line 52, in run_main runner(addr, name, kind == 'module', *extra,
>   **kwargs) File "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\runner.py",
>   line 32, in run set_trace=False) File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
>   line 1283, in run return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn,
>   module_name, file, globals, locals) File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
>   line 1290, in _exec pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #
>   execute the script File
>   "c:\Users\gubert.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd_vendored\pydevd_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py",
>   line 25, in execfile exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob,
>   loc) File "c:\Users\gubert\Repos\Gimmonix\HotelMappingAI\test.py",
>   line 8, in  ws = Workspace.from_config() File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\workspace.py",
>   line 153, in from_config auth=auth) File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\workspace.py",
>   line 86, in init auto_rest_workspace = _commands.get_workspace(auth,
>   subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name) File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml_project_commands.py",
>   line 326, in get_workspace resource_error_handling(response_exception,
>   WORKSPACE) File
>   "C:\Users\gubert.azureml\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml_base_sdk_common\common.py",
>   line 270, in resource_error_handling raise
>   ProjectSystemException(response_message)
>   azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.ProjectSystemException: {
>   "error_details": { "error": { "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
>   "message": "The client 'xxxxxxxxxx@microsoft.com' with object id
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/read' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/CarsolizeCloud - Test
>   Global/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/gmx-ml-mapping'."
>   } }, "status_code": 403, "url":
>   "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/CarsolizeCloud%20-%20Test%20Global/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/gmx-ml-mapping?api-version=2018-03-01-preview"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Try using the newest SDK version 1.0.10, this is a fairly old preview version you're using. If you still have a problem, let me know as I work on this SDK.